# How to close dialogbox and load datagrid after dialogbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

This is my frm_item code. it show the frm_search as a dialogbox.

```
private void txtCat_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)`
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {

                Software.frm_search search = new Software.frm_search();
                search.MyValue = "CATEGORY";
                DialogResult result = search.ShowDialog();


                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    int cate_id = int.Parse(cat_id.Text);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = ConObj.exec("SELECT code as 'Code Number',item_name as 'Item Name',active as 'Active' FROM items WHERE id_category = '" + cate_id + "'");
                    dtgItem.DataSource = dt;
                    ConObj.disconnect();
                }
                search.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Here is my code from my frm_search. After the keydown my frm_item shows but this form is not closing.

```cs
Request.frm_item item = new Request.frm_item();
        public string MyValue { get; set; }`
`private void dgList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {`
                
                switch (label2.Text = MyValue)
                {
                    //MyValue = CATEGORY
                    case "CATEGORY":
                        item.txtCat.Text = dgList.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        item.cat_id.Text = dgList.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        item.ShowDialog();
                        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                        Close();
                        break;
                    
                }

            }
        }
```

I want to close the `frm_search` after the `keydown` event and also my datagrid `dtgItem` in `frm_item` is not showing the data.

Comment: sorry for my post. Why I cant insert the other code in the mark code?

Comment: You appear to be calling `ShowDialog` on the search form from the item form, then calling `ShowDialog` on the item form from the search form. How does that make sense? The search form should not know anything about the item form. The search form should simply expose the selected data via one or more properties and close. The item form should then retrieve the data from those properties and update itself.

Comment: BTW, there's no need or point to calling `Close` after setting the `DialogResult` property. Once you set that property, the form will close.

Comment: Note that you parse `cat_id.Text` and then concatenate it into the middle of your `Where` clause. DON'T DO THAT! Read up on _SQL Injection_ and about [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to use your actual code because there's not enough there to really know what's going on. I'll provide an example that will illustrate the principle of getting user input via a dialogue though. In this example, `Form1` will display `Form2`, the user will enter data into `TextBox1` on `Form2` and then click the OK `Button`. `Form2` will expose the user input via a property and `Form1` will retrieve that property value and display it in `Label1`.

Form1:

```cs
using (var dialogue = new Form2())
{
    if (dialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK)
    {
        label1.Text = dialogue.Data;
    }
}
```

Form2:

```cs
public string Data
{
    get => textBox1.Text;
}
    
private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
    
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

That's all there is to it. In this case, the property simply returns the data directly from the control. In a more complex case, you may have to set one or more properties explicitly before setting the `DialogResult` to `OK`. If, for instance, you had a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable` via a `BindingSource` and you want to get some field values from the selected row, you might do this:

```cs
public string Data1
{
    get => ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row.Field<string>("Column1");
}

public string Data2
{
    get => ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row.Field<string>("Column2");
}
```

or you might do this:

```cs
public string Data1 { get; private set; }
public string Data2 { get; private set; }
```

and then this:

```cs
Data1 = ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row.Field<string>("Column1");
Data2 = ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row.Field<string>("Column2");
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```